# pyautogui does not show me my mouse position in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyautogui

I installed pyautogui i run the following code but nothing happens. I get no error or etc.

import pyautogui
pyautogui.displayMousePosition()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
import pyautogui
print(pyautogui.position())
#this will return (x, y) coordinates
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need this code:

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    print (pyautogui.position())
```

Comment: Thanks mate i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui as lms

getinfo = currentMouseX, currentMouseY = lms.position() <br>
print(getinfo)
```

This is the simple code for the x and y coordinate.